# How to show that the matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, similar-matrices

> Let $A, B$ be two $n \times n$ matrices over a field $F$ and $A,B$ have the same characteristic and minimal polynomials. If no eigenvalue has algebraic multiplicity greater than $6$ and the solution space of $A-c_iI$ and $B-c_iI$ are same then $A$ and $B$ are similar (characteristic polynomial of $A,B$ is $f = (x - c_1)^{d_1} \cdots (x - c_k)^{d_k}$).

I have to use the following result.

> If $A, B$ are two $6 \times 6$ nilpotent matrices, then $A, B$ are similar if and only if they have same minimal polynomial and the same nullity.

These are exercises from Hoffman and Kunze. I have proved the second result. I am not sure how to use this to prove the first result. I was thinking of breaking it into cases but that is becoming too long. Any hint would be appreciated rather than a complete answer.

Comment: Use the Primary Decomposition Theorem to write $V=\bigoplus V_i$ where the $V_i$ are $A$ invariant and on $V_i$ the characteristic polynomial is $(x-c_i)^{d_i}$.

Comment: But $d_i$ are not necessarily $6$ then where am I suppose to use the second result?

Comment: Isn't the result (which you've proved) not true for dimension $k$ with $k\leqslant 6$?

Comment: One approach for the second result: consider the rational forms of $A$, or equivalently its cyclic decompositions. Their invariant factors must satisfy $p_1 \mid \cdots \mid p_k$ with $p_k$ equal to the minimal polynomial and the product $p_1 \cdots p_k$ equal to the characteristic polynomial, which must be $p(x) = x^6$.

Show that the nullity of $A$ is equal to $k$, the number of invariant factors in its decomposition. Use this to conclude that if $A,B$ are nilpotent with the same minimal polynomial and nullity, then they must have the same invariant factors.